# Send email from windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to sent an email from windows phone 8.1 app.Email Compose task not working in it.
I tried this

```
EmailRecipient sendTo = new EmailRecipient()
{
    Address = "abc@outlook.com"
};

//generate mail object
EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage();
mail.Subject = "Feedback";


//add recipients to the mail object
mail.To.Add(sendTo);
//mail.Bcc.Add(sendTo);
//mail.CC.Add(sendTo);

//open the share contract with Mail only:
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
```

This gives an error in the emulator:

> Can't share
>   There are no apps to share with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any Email accounts in your emulator to share from that account. If you want to send an email, you should have an account right?

So go to **email + accounts** in Settings menu and add an account of any type in Emulator. Once you finish adding an email account, try deploying the app in the Emulator and perform the task. You should able to see Email task right now.

Since there is no email account in the emulator, "It shows no apps to share, Can't share now".

Answer (score 3):

On emulator, login with your Microsoft account and try again. I solved this with login account.

Answer (score 2):

You can test it on **Device**. Because on your Emulator, there are not any mail account at all. So when you call `ShowComposeNewEmailAsync` method, it can't find any target.
Or you can add account on your Emulator in Setting -> email+account.