# Send email from windows phone 8.1 app(c#). Using any SMTP server , I am trying using gmail smtp

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing Windows phone application using VS 2013. In this I want to send email from some app pages like contact support page.

I have tried the c# working code from a windows console app. But 'Mailmessage' keyword is not supported in windows phone app development .

I have tried 'EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);' code from [Send email from windows phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816227/send-email-from-windows-phone-8-1).
That is result in opening mail messanger app available in the devices/emulator. I don't want the mail messenger app to open. Instead I want send to email through only code...

How can I achieve this?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send email without showing the email application to the user. Also, the user might have many emails so he needs to decide from which the message should be sent.

What you can do is send whatever you want to send by email to a server (for example using HttpWebRequest) and from there send the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the message without displaying a standard message box.

The user should monitor the sent message.

This is a safety feature for Windows Phone.

Only use ShowComposeNewEmailAsync.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So your saying that We can't send email without user action?. Could you please give me links where I can get official confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

To send mail using SMTP in Windows Phone you can make use of [MailMessage for WP8 & WP7](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage).

It's not a free package, but you can make you use of it's free version.
It's free license never expires, but opens a popup message and add a sponsor string to both object and body.

Refer here for more : [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailMessage/)

Comment: There are another Nuget Packages also present to do this : 


Mail.dll

1) [Mail For Windows Store.dll Windows 8+/Phone 8.1](http://www.limilabs.com/mail-for-windows-store) 

2) [Mail.dll email component (IMAP,POP3, SMTP, MIME, SSL)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f0bf18a6-883c-4282-84ff-02d826fa7a1e)

Answer (score 0):

First, I work with **Xamarin.Forms**.
As the (other) question to Xamarin.Forms is marked as "duplicate" of this question, I post my answer here.
I also think, it's not possible (and also would not be nice), if Emails would be set in the background (without user interaction).
Therefore, I let the users send EMail's over the device-object in my app:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:" + oFreizeitDetails.cPAB_Mailadresse));
```

where "oFreizeitDetails.cPAB_Mailadresse" contains the mail-address as string.
This works, **if a mail-client is installed** on the device.

The mail-client then pops up, the target mail-address is prefilled and the user can finish the mail (add body-text, e.t.c.) and then send it.
There were some problems with the WP implementation in XF some time ago, but now (I work with **XF 1.4.4** and WP **8.1**), it also works with WP.